# Is it possible to add parent class properties in child class properties at end?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to create a table using EntityFramework and have a Entity "**Derived**" inherited from **Base** class. like this

```
public class Base 
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime  CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Derived : Base
{
    public int Name { get; set; }    
}
```

And it creates this table **Derived(ID, CreatedDate, Name)** But i want CreatedDate at last of every Child Class Propoerties. Is it possible without using Order attribute?

Comment: Do you mean the order of fields within your table when you say "at last of every child"?

Comment: Why would you not want to use the `OrderAttribute`? That is what it does.

Comment: @HimBromBeere yes

Comment: @bolkay, I have to set a positive integer value for Order attribute right? but in future if child table's columns get increased then this will make issue? Please correct me if i am wrong. I am just thinking.

Comment: You can probably  configure this in OnModelCreating.  But the mechanism is different between EF6 and EF Core.  Which are you using?